# How to translate $url_handlers?

Tags: silverstripe

I have a situation where I need to translate the following `$url_handlers` for different countries.

So on an english site the URL looks like this: http://website.com/gyms/boston/group-training

I need to be able to translate the "group-training" part of the URL. I have translated the rest of the site using the `_t()` method throughout.

My current setup:

```
class GymLocationPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {

    private static $allowed_actions = array(
        'currentSpecials',
        'sevenDayFreeTrial',
        'groupTraining'
    );

    private static $url_handlers = array(
        'current-specials' => 'currentSpecials',
        'trial' => 'sevenDayFreeTrial',
        'group-training' => 'groupTraining'
    );


}
```

How would one achieve this?

Comment: I'd be very interested in this, because I'm not sure you can...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could update the config inside the controller's init() function, doing something like this:

```php
public function init() {

    parent::init();

    // Define your translated actions.
    $translatedCurrentSpecials   = _t('Actions.CURRENT_SPECIALS', 'aktuella-kampanjer');
    $translatedSevenDayFreeTrial = _t('Actions.SEVEN_DAY_TRIAL',  'sjudagars-prova-pa-period');

    // Define your url handlers.
    $urlHandlers           = $this->config()->url_handlers;
    $translatedUrlHandlers = [
        $translatedCurrentSpecials   => 'currentSpecials',
        $translatedSevenDayFreeTrial => 'sevenDayFreeTrial'
    ];

    // Update the config.
    Config::inst()->update(
        $this->class, 
        'url_handlers', 
        $translatedUrlHandlers + $urlHandlers // Important to prepend and not append.
    );

}
```

Comment: Perfect! I found I didn't need to set the `$allowed_actions` in the `init`. I just set the allowed actions like you normally would in the `private static $allowed_actions` but set the $url_handlers in the init as per your code. Thanks so much! :)

Comment: We had this discussion two years ago at the first StripeCon in Linz, Austria, I coded a working example, see https://github.com/wernerkrauss/silverstripe-translatable-actions