# Silverstripe allowed_action translation in url address

Tags: internationalization, silverstripe

I want to know how to make allowed_actions match i18n language of the site. All modules that I saw not offer that option.

Case of usage : I make a Form page submission module and I would like to translate the submited page url  'finished' (English, EN) with another language like mine 'termine' (French, FR).

Url://exemple/contactpage/finished

To

Url://exemple/contactpage/termine

Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: I don't know anything about silverstripe, av this is not an answer. But I promise you that you will run into troubles with this approach. You will find there are several languages using the same word, sometimes for the same concept, sometimes for different concepts. How do you plan to deal with that?

Comment: @MihaiNita I'm not sure this would be a problem if the pages' URLs are translated as well (which can be achieved in SilverStripe). Example: `https://site.tld/{translate.contact}/{translate.contact_finished}`  -> (en_GB) `https://site.tld/contact/finished` -> (sv_SE) `https://site.tld/kontakt/genomford`. As long as the translations are well made I don't think there will be any confusion. But I might have misinterpreted the question.

Comment: Two different languages might end up with the same URL. For instance "Help" is translated into Dutch as ... "Help". So the https://site.tld/help page should take you to what page, the English or the Dutch one? You might say "the .tld is country specific". Maybe. But it can also happen in a multilingual country, like Canada, or Switzerland. "Page" in French is ... "page". So https://site.ca/page will take you to... You need the language ID as a sub-path: http://site.ca/fr/page vs http://site.ca/en/page

Comment: @Mihai Nita : Ok I'm understand your mean. But dont worry of that. The module I make is for a single language first and configured into the main config file. I don't think with a fiew modifications my module will not go with another multilingual module... It's not my expectation at now. Thanks for reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class SimpleContactPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {

    private static $allowed_actions = array(
        'finished'
    );

    public function finished() {
        ...
    }

    public function init() {

        parent::init();

        $translatedAction   = _t('SimpleContactPage.CONTROLLER', 'finished');
        $urlHandlers        = $this->config()->url_handlers;

        $translatedUrlHandlers = array(
            $translatedAction   => 'finished',
        );

        Config::inst()->update(
            $this->class, 
            'url_handlers', 
            $translatedUrlHandlers + $urlHandlers
        );

    }

}
```

Thanks to that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39162402/how-to-translate-url-handlers) that I found ->
Author : [Janne Klouman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2298963/janne-klouman)